# I want to close all gui in one button when i make many gui. Any one know how to do it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When i press the make gui button many time i will get a lot of gui but when i press the close gui button it will close one gui. Why?

```
 from tkinter import *

   showw = Tk()
   showw.withdraw()

   def Quit(event):

      showw.withdraw()

   def show(event):
        global showw
        global cnt
        showxyUI = Tk()
        showxyUI.title("X and Y ")
        showxyUI.geometry("200x100")
        showw = showxyUI
  programInterface = Tk()
  programInterface.title("GUI")

  myButton = Button(programInterface,text="make gui",bg="red",fg="white",width= 20,height=3)
  myButton.bind('<Button-1>',show)
  myButton.pack()
  button = Button(programInterface,text="close gui",bg="red",fg="white",width= 20,height=3)
  button.bind('<Button-1>',Quit)
  button.pack()
  programInterface.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggest you write a clear code!
(Choose suitable name, whitespace and etc.)
This convention, increase readability and makes your code easy for debugging.

```
from tkinter import *

popup_list = []


def quit_all():
    popup_list.pop().destroy()


def create_popup():
    popup = Tk()
    popup.title("Pop-Up window")
    popup.geometry("200x100")
    popup_list.append(popup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Tk()
    main.title("GUI")

    make_button = Button(main, text="make popup", bg="red", fg="white", width=20, height=3, command=create_popup)
    make_button.pack()

    quit_button = Button(main, text="close popup", bg="red", fg="white", width=20, height=3, command=quit_all)
    quit_button.pack()

    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry for that and Thank you.

Comment: It helps me nicely. Thank:) @niMa Moh